# BOOL changing value in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I am having trouble with a `BOOL` property and I can't quite figure it out.

I have the following set in my .h file:

```
BOOL myVar;

@property BOOL myVar;
```

Then in my .m file I synthesize `myVar` and have a method that set `myVar = YES;` and also starts a timer. The timer then calls another method that tries to read the value of myVar.

To test for the value of myVar I have:

```
NSLog(@"The value of the bool is %@\n", (myVar ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

The first loop through the console shows `myVar = YES` then after that it says NO.

How do I keep it as the value of `YES`? Is it already `YES` but my NSLog is wrong? I need to test for YES/NO in that method because the actions taken will vary depending on their value.

Comment: Can you post a minimal set of code that demonstrates the problem? You can also look at manually writing out the setter for the property and placing a breakpoint in it. This will let you see if something else is changing the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it was failing was because I was comparing (myVar = YES) instead of (myVar == YES.)

Yeah -- I am new.

Answer (score 2):

Set a watch point on `myVar` to find out if it actually changes, with out seeing more source code we can't tell you what is going on :)